# how to put a lightbox in a popup in leaflet

Tags: html, google-maps, popup, leaflet, lightbox

I want the image to be enlarged in a light box when click of a particular popup on google maps in leaflet and also how to make map size resizeable

**here is my code**

```
 <body>
      <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
      <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([42.307755, -83.067849], 13);

       L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
               id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(map);

         var ly=L.marker([45.307755, -89.067849]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<b>U</b><br /> k").openPopup();
          var ln=L.marker([45.305422, -83.065374]).bindPopup('Tower').addTo(map);


      </script>
     </body>
```

Comment: What image do you want to enlarge?

Comment: any image from laptop will work